# Procedure uploading a web-app to Firebase

Tags: reactjs, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

Though I have set up several web apps on `Firebase` in the past. This time I am having problems uploading this one to the server.

The special thing about this app is that I am using React.

I followed [this tutorial](https://www.educative.io/edpresso/firebase-as-simple-database-to-react-app), did the following to get started in the terminal:

```
$ npx create-react-app myapp
$ cd myapp/
$ npm install firebase --save
$ npm start
```

And then after spending much time working on the React side of things to get something close enough to my taste, at this point I can see the app running, on port 3000 (http://localhost:3000/), in the browser as I expect. It is also accessing a Realtime database on the sever as I want. The next step is for me to have the app itself run on the server and not only on my localhost as it is now. **What do I need to do for that?**
I have made a few trials based on my previous experience with Firebase, running "firebase deploy" (+ some other things), but it is not working. The app is not on the server. More precisely, it shows a white page.

As a complementary piece of information, this is my *firebase.json* file:

```
{
  "database": {
    "rules": "database.rules.json"
  },
  "hosting": {
    "public": "public",
    "ignore": [
      "firebase.json",
      "**/.*",
      "**/node_modules/**"
    ]
  }
}
```

And this is how the *public* directory looks:

```
...$ ls public/
404.html    index.html  logo512.png robots.txt
favicon.ico logo192.png manifest.json
...$
```

Comment: Did you build the app before deploying? Also can you share your firebase.json file and a screenshot of your directory strcuture?r

Comment: @Dharmaraj. I tried once running "npm run build" before running "firebase deploy"; but with no particular success. (Is this what you mean by "build the app before deploying"?). I added the firebase.json file at the end of the post, please have a look. For the directory structure, it is quite long, so it would be nice if you could tell me precisely what you need to know or what I need to check.

Comment: Yes. What's the name of build folder? Right now your firebase.json looks for a folder `'public'` and deploys that.

Comment: I added the contents of the public folder at the end of the post, in case that may be useful. Beside I am not aware of setting the name of the build folder anywhere.

Comment: @Dharmaraj. Following your comments, I did some directory exploring along with some thinking; and tried to replace inside the firebase.json file "public" by "build" for the "public" fields inside "hosting". And the result (after rerunning: firebase deploy) is a success, I can now see my app running directly on the server. Please feel free to add any further comment you may have.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You must build your React app (`npm run build` or your build command) and then make sure that `public` directory in `firebase.json` is your `build` folder.

```
{
  "hosting": {
    "public": "build", // name of build output directory
  }
}
```

In your case it was set to `public` and hence that directory was being deployed.